# Factoring this binomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring

How would I factor this? 
$$\frac1{16}x^{3a}+\frac12y^{6a}z^{9b}$$
Even after plugging it into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F16x%5E(3a)%2B1%2F2y%5E(6a)z%5E(9b)) I didn't get anything useful.... As far as I see, it isn't a square, cubic, quartic, quintic... etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT.-$$\frac1{16}x^{3a}+\frac12y^{6a}z^{9b}=\frac 12\left((\frac{x^a}{2})^3+(y^{2a}z^{3b})^3\right) $$

Apply now $A^3+B^3=(A+B)(A^2-AB+B^2)$ with $A=\frac{x^a}{2}$ and $B=y^{2a}z^{3b}$.